# Running sudo on a bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I have a script that starts like this:

```
source /etc/os-release
if [ $NAME = 'Ubuntu' ]
```

And it runs fine as a normal user. However, if I invoke it like:

```
$ sudo ./install.sh
```

I get the following error:

> ./install.sh: 9: ./install.sh: source: not found

> ./install.sh: 10: [: =: unexpected operator

Why does that occur when in `sudo` mode, and what's required to fix that?

Comment: Show your shebang.

Comment: Please provide a full [mre] in your question

Comment: The error message `./install.sh: source: not found` indicates that the script is being run under a POSIX shell like `dash` (which is the default `/bin/sh` on many systems).  The `source` command is a feature of `bash` and similar shells.

Comment: @Cyrus I don't have a shebang in the file.

Answer (score 1):

Read the documentation of [sudo(8)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/sudo.8.html) and of [execve(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) (used by `sudo`) and of [bash(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html). Read also the documentation of [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) (or of your interactive [Unix shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell), perhaps [zsh](https://zsh.org/) or [fish](https://fishshell.com); use [chsh(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chsh.1.html) to change it)

Either your `./install.sh` script (starting with a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))) should be made executable with [chmod(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chmod.1.html), or you *explicitly* need to invoke `/bin/bash` -or `/bin/sh`- to run it (and have it being readable).

So try `chmod a+x ./install.sh` before `sudo ./install.sh`  or else run `sudo /bin/bash ./install.sh`

I recommend taking several days to read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/) then [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) and [credentials(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html)

You could also study for inspiration and self teaching the source code of simple shells (most of them are [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source)) such as [sash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stand-alone_shell), or of [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) or at least use [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) or [ltrace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ltrace.1.html) or [gdb(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gdb.1.html) to understand their runtime behavior.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sudo chmod a+x install.sh
Sudo ./install.sh
```

Basically the install.sh needs the correct permissions.

Chmod : change mode permissions of the file
a : for all users
+x: add execute permissons

Comment: If that was the issue then OP would see an *Operation not permitted* error, not *source: not found* and the like.